# Why does addition of MigLayout still give an error inspite of adding the MigLayout jar file in the libraries in netbeans 8.0?

Tags: netbeans, miglayout

Though I have configured the classpath and added the jar file in the library of the project , it still gives me an error as "package net.miginfocom.swing. does not exist". 
What can I do to avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

You can use maven to automatically download MigLayout. Just click new project, select and maven from categories, then Java Application. Once created go into the "pom.xml" (within Project Files) and paste this under the properties section:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.miglayout</groupId>
        <artifactId>miglayout</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Then just build the project and maven will download and install MigLayout. Hope this helps.

Comment: @ninja coder Could you post some example code, with the imports, that outputs this error?